# ASP.NETでAjaxControlToolkitでToolkitScriptManagerが不明な要素エラーとでる

Tags: asp.net

AjaxControlToolkitを使おうとしてエラーになるのですが、解決方法をご存じの方がいましたらお願いします。
最新のインストーラでVisualStudio2013にインストールしました。
アプリケーションはASP.NETフォームアプリケーションを空から作成しているものです。
プロジェクトの参照設定の配下にはAjaxControlToolkitが存在しています。

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
中略
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:CalendarExtender ID="TextBox1_CalendarExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="TextBox1"></asp:CalendarExtender>
 <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
 </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

エラー。
型または名前空間名 'ToolkitScriptManager' は名前空間 'AjaxControlToolkit' に存在しません。アセンブリ参照が不足しています。

ページのデザイナーの一番したのToolkitScriptManagerに赤線が引かれていてエラーになっています。その前のCalendarExtenderはなぜかエラーになっていないです。

```
    /// <summary>
    /// TextBox1 コントロール。
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// 自動生成されたフィールド。
    /// 変更するには、フィールドの宣言をデザイナー ファイルから分離コード ファイルに移動します。
    /// </remarks>
    protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox TextBox1;

    /// <summary>
    /// TextBox1_CalendarExtender コントロール。
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// 自動生成されたフィールド。
    /// 変更するには、フィールドの宣言をデザイナー ファイルから分離コード ファイルに移動します。
    /// </remarks>
    protected global::AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarExtender TextBox1_CalendarExtender;

    /// <summary>
    /// ToolkitScriptManager1 コントロール。
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// 自動生成されたフィールド。
    /// 変更するには、フィールドの宣言をデザイナー ファイルから分離コード ファイルに移動します。
    /// </remarks>
    protected global::AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager ToolkitScriptManager1;
```

web.configの内容は次の内容です。

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  </assemblies>
 </compilation>
 <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
 <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="logon.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH"/>
 </authentication>
 <authorization>
   <deny users="?"/>
 </authorization>

 <pages>
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="asp"
         namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"
         assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" />
  </controls>
</pages>

  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ToolkitScriptManager`は[既に削除されていうようです](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ToolkitScriptManager%20Removed%20in%20v15.1%2C%20Use%20ScriptManager)。代替としては標準の`ScriptManager`を使用せよとのことです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
ScriptManagerに修正したところ、正しく動作しました。